# HTML iso-8859-1 not showing characters 'åäö'

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm using the charset iso-8859-1 for my .JSP page like this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"" />
```

When running this page, normal text like

```
<p> ååä </p>
```

is displayed, but

```
<h2> åäö </h2>
```

is not displayed at all. Any suggestions to why this is happening?

**edit:**

this is my css code for the h2 tag, if it is of itrest:

```
h2 { font-size:36px; line-height:45px; color:#c1baba; font-weight:normal; letter-spacing:-1px;}
```

**edit2:**

Encoding of my .JSP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

referenced CSS file (style2.css) is set to

```
@CHARSET "utf-8";
```

head of .JSP page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="css/style2.css">
<title>Start</title>
</head>
```

Comment: "is not" how? wrong chars? not showing up at all?

Comment: Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and see what are you getting?

Comment: It's not showing up at all @MarcB

Comment: @Aditya same problem.

Comment: Can you set this `header('Content-type: text/html; charset='ISO-8859-1');` use JSP ?

Comment: @Aditya I'm not very familiar with JS, how would I do this?

Comment: Do that with JSP ? something like `system.out.println('header('Content-type: text/html; charset='ISO-8859-1');` pardon me, i dont know JSP

Comment: What is the **actual** encoding of the *.jsp file? What is the actual HTTP `Content-Type` header value being sent to the client?

Comment: You need to post an example that actually reproduces the problem. The cause of the problems is *not* in the code you have included.

Comment: Stupid question, but do ASCII characters in the h2 work as expected? Also, if you apply the CSS to the `p` also, does it still work?

Comment: encoding issue. use utf-8 encoding. Also save file as utf-8.

Comment: Check edit2 @MrLister

Comment: Chceck edit2 @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: This is not an encoding issue, if the characters are written the same way inside `h2` as inside `p`. The code posted still does not reproduce the problem. You need to post a complete (preferably minimal) document, HTML and CSS, that actually causes the phenomenon described in the question. (My current guess is that some fancy font face is used for `h2` and the font is broken, e.g. has empty glyphs for åäö.)

Comment: This issue was caused by a referenced javascript that replaced the default font with a font that didn't support special characters. I changed the font and it works. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a referenced javascript that replaced the default font with a font that didn't support special characters. I changed the font and it works.

Comment: @MrLister yes, good call. Changed it.